# PHP obtaining data from strings

Tags: php, regex, string

I have asked several questions regarding this and I have tried many different things, but I am not completely happy with it.  I have a lot of data in the following format

```
3*O#AA6160 F7 A7 P7 J7 R7 D7 I7 Y7 LHRMIA 1040 1455   *  744 0E
        B7 H0 W0 K0 M0 L0 V0 G0 S0 Q0 N0 O0
```

The spaces you see on the second row are there by default.  Essentially, from that string I am trying to get the following

```
$flightNumber = AA6160;
$from = LHR;
$to = MIA;
$other = 1040 1455   *  744 0E;
$seats = array(
    "F" => 7,
    "A" => 7,
    "P" => 7,
    "J" => 7,
    "R" => 7,
    "D" => 7,
    "I" => 7,
    "Y" => 7,
    "B" => 7,
    "H" => 0,
    "W" => 0,
    "K" => 0,
    "M" => 0,
    "L" => 0,
    "V" => 0,
    "G" => 0,
    "S" => 0,
    "Q" => 0,
    "O" => 0,
)
```

The rules are as follows.
The start of a row starts with a digit (in the above case 3).  The second row is a continuation of seats from the first row.  If I was to post the full data I have, the third row starts with 4 which means that its not related to the two above.

A flight number always starts with a # and is following by TWO Letters and 1-4 numbers.  Sometimes there is spaces between the letters and numbers.  These are all the types of flight numbers I have discovered

```
#AA6160
#AA  57
#BA 207
```

The second row will only contain a continuation of seats, nothing else.  This is what I have come up with so far

```
while ( $elNum < $elements->length ) {

    $flightInfo = $elements->item($elNum)->nodeValue;

    if (preg_match('/^\\d/', $flightInfo) === 1) {
        if(preg_match('/(\d)+[^#]*?\#(\p{Lu}{2})\s*(\d{1,4})\b\s*([\w. ]+?)(?=\s+\p{Lu}{6})\s([A-Z]{3})([A-Z]{3})(.+)/', $flightInfo, $matches)===1){
            $row = $matches[1];
            $fltcode = $matches[2].$matches[3];
            $ffrom = $matches[5];
            $fto = $matches[6];
            $other = $matches[7];

            $this->flights[$fltcode] = array(
                "command" => $terminal_command,
                "row" => $row,
                "flightNumber" => $fltcode,
                "from" => $ffrom,
                "to" => $fto,
                "other" => $other
            );
        }
    }
    ++$elNum;
}
```

The main thing I am struggling with is the seats.  I am not sure how to get the ones I need from the first row and combine them with the ones from the second row in the output format I need them all to be.

I am not even sure if regex is the best option here, or if I should explode everything on spaces and sort them like this?

Any advice on the situation is appreciated.  Here is some additional data

```
5*S#DL4386 J9 C9 D9 I9 Z9 W9 Y9 B9 LHRMIA 1235 1705   *  744 0E
        M9 S9 H9 Q9 K9 L9 U9 T9 X9 V9 
6  #VS   5 J9 C9 D9 I9 Z9 W9 S9 H9 LHRMIA 1235 1705      744 0E
        K9 Y9 B9 R9 L9 U9 M9 E9 Q9 X9 N9 O9 
7  #IB4637 F9 A9 J9 C9 D9 R9 I. W9 LHRMIA 1415 1825   *  744 0E
        Z. Y9 B9 H9 K. M. L. V. S. N. Q. O.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example that uses XMLReader instead of DOMDocument for the xml parsing, because it is faster and use less memory. The patterns are designed to be more readable (with the free-spacing mode and the named captures) and efficient (with anchors, without useless unicode character classes like `\p{Lu}`, lookaheads, or unused capturing groups).

```
$xml = <<<EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root xmlns:terminal="http://test.com/terminal">
    <terminal:Text>1  #AY5767 F9 A9 P. J9 C9 D9 I9 Y9 LHRMIA 0945 1410   *  777 0E</terminal:Text>
    <terminal:Text>        B9 H9 K9 M9 L9 V9 S9 N9 Q9 O9 G9 </terminal:Text>

    <otherthings>blah blah blah</otherthings>

    <terminal:Text>2  #AY5768 F9 A9 P. J9 C9 D9 I9 Y9 ROMMIL 0945 1410   *  777 0E</terminal:Text>
    <terminal:Text>        B9 H9 K9 M9 L9 V9 S9 N9 Q9 O9 G9 </terminal:Text>
    <terminal:Text>        E8 G8 R8 S8 T4 U2 </terminal:Text>
</root>
EOD;

$patternFirstLine = <<<EOD
~
\A
    [0-9]+ \s+
    \# (?<code1> [A-Z]{2} ) \s* (?<code2> [0-9]{1,4} ) \s+ 
    (?<seat1> [A-Z][0-9.] (?: \s+ [A-Z][0-9.] )*+ ) \s+
    (?<from> [A-Z]{3} ) (?<to> [A-Z]{3} ) \s+
    (?<other> .*\S ) \s*
\z
~x
EOD;

$patternNextLines = <<<EOD
~
\A \s*
    (?<seatN> [A-Z][0-9.] (?: \s+ [A-Z][0-9.] )*+ )
\s* \z
~x
EOD;

$parser = new XMLReader();

$parser->xml($xml);

$temp = false;
$results = [];

while($parser->read()) {
    while ($parser->name === 'terminal:Text') {
        if (preg_match($patternFirstLine, $parser->readInnerXML(), $m)) {
            if ($temp) $results[] = $temp;

            $temp = [
                "flightNumber" => $m['code1'] . $m['code2'],
                "from"         => $m['from'],
                "to"           => $m['to'],
                "seats"        => $m['seat1'],
                "other"        => $m['other']
            ];
        } elseif ($temp && preg_match($patternNextLines, $parser->readInnerXML(), $m))
            $temp['seats'] .= ' ' . $m['seatN'];
        else
            $temp = false;

        $parser->next('Text');

    }
}

if ($temp) $results[] = $temp;

$results = array_map(function ($i) {
    $seats = explode(' ',$i['seats']);
    $i['seats'] = [];
    foreach ($seats as $seat)
        $i['seats'][$seat[0]] = $seat[1];

    return $i;
}, $results);

print_r($results);
```

Note: in this example, I use `XMLReader::xml()` to load the xml content, but one of the main interest of `XMLReader` is to use the [`XMLReader::open`](http://php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.open.php) method with the xml uri.

Comment: Thats fantastic, just going over it now to learn it properly.  One thing I am trying to work out is this.  I have a variable called $responseData which is basically a string containing my Soap data (it should be XML formed).  How could I load this instead?  I have tried using open but it says it can't open the source data

Comment: I don't think you can use `XMLReader::open` since you need to query a SOAP service to get your datas. But you can always use `XMLReader::xml` with `$responseData`

Comment: $responseData already holds the data from the Soap Service.  I have tried using it with XMLReader::xml but it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something more simple, but I'm not 100% sure, that this covers everything you need.

```
function yourFunction($input) {
    // get the individual words, meaning split on whitespace
    $words = preg_split('/\s+/', $input);
    // filter the words the best we can
    $valuableInput = array_filter($words, function($word) {
        $chars = str_split($word); 
        return count($chars) == 2 && is_int($chars[1]);
    });

    // Create the mapping between the characters and the numbers
    $output = array();
    foreach ($valuableInput as $word) {
        $chars = str_split($word);
        $output[$chars[0]] = $chars[1]; 
    }
    return $output;
}
```